# Air Compressor or pump for raspi?

Tags: sensor

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi to inflate a balloon. To do that I need a pump/compressor that I can control (essentially turn on/off, but psi readings would be great too) with the Pi. In my research, I haven't found a pump that was specifically built to be connected to the Pi. Do you have any recommendations regarding pumps? 
We're talking about a regularly sized party balloon here. And the pump/compressor should be as small as possible, but still powerful enough to inflate the balloon in under a minute.

Comment: And what the role of the Pi would be?

Comment: There is a web console to start the pump, read the pressure, display it, stop the pump once the preset pressure is reached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get a cheap tire inflator (one that lets you set the pressure) that runs from a cigarette lighter. Then I would cut the plug off the power cable, attach it to a 12V relay, and control the relay from the Pi. To avoid needing another power source to run the relay you might want to look for a relay board designed specifically for the Pi (these are widely available from the usual Pi suppliers).

Comment: This seems doable and very cheap, thank you! Would it be possible to add this sensor to the mix to read out the air pressure of the balloon?
HONEYWELL ABPLANT005PG2A3

Comment: FYI you did not link to a sensor. But most of the inflators come with a pressure gauge built in. The one I have you turn the dial to set the pressure at which the compressor turns off. If you want another pressure gauge you could cobble together a little plumbing and insert the gauge between the compressor output and the balloon.

Comment: I was not allowed to link it, thatswhy I pasted the name of the sensor for google-fu purposes ;) The issue is, that I want to control the pump based on the pressure in the balloon. A preset or fixed pressure isn't working for me

Comment: My comments still apply.